# Matching dynamically created associative arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, matching

I need to concatenate multiple associative arrays in my javascript, such as below:

```
array1 = [{model: 1995}, {type: "automatic"}]

array2 = [{model: 2002}, {type: "automatic"}]

array3 = [{model: 1995}, {type: "automatic"}]

array4 = [{model: 2002}, {type: "automatic"}]
```

I need to concatenate the array only if the 'model' values match, so array1.concat(array3).. However these values are created dynamically and i need a way of matching these.

Ive tried:

```
   if (array1[0].model === array2[0].model) {
     concatenated = array1.concat(array2) }
```

However this doesn't cycle through all the arrays to find the matches, it just matches the first two arrays it identifies as having the same model?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you ar trying to do?

```
var array1 = [{model: 1995}, {type: "automatic"}];

var array2 = [{model: 2002}, {type: "automatic"}];

var array3 = [{model: 1995}, {type: "automatic"}];

var array4 = [{model: 2002}, {type: "automatic"}];

var all = [array1, array2, array3, array4];

var model1995 = all.filter(function(array) {
  return array[0].model === 1995;
});

var model2002 = all.filter(function(array) {
  return array[0].model === 2002;
});
```